# Set backbone model attribute value to another model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Can I set another backbone model as its attribute ?

I have a model that represents a basic entity, I 'd like to reuse it as part of something else.
But, it looks like Backbone's model attribute value can only be String.

Answer (score 2):

Sort answer: **yes you can**:

```
myHouse.set({ door: new Door() })
```

But, in my opinion, is not a good idea to do so, because I don't think Backbone is expecting to found `Objects` in the `Model.attributes`. I didn't try but I don't think methods like `Model.toJSON` are gonna have a correct behavior if someone of the *attributes* is an Object.

But said so, I don't see any problem to declare *real attributes* in the Model that make reference to objects like:

```
myHouse.door = new Door();
```

Comment: I believe that this will work like a charm. The documentation also says that is a common practice to nest a collection inside a model, so I don't see why a nested model would hurt. So, +1 for the answer and [here is the part I'm talking about](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-nested)

Comment: If anything I would go for declaring submodels and subcollections as REAL attributes, as to not 'filthen' the model's attributes. plus you would have to overwrite your toJSON method to recursively go over your submodules and collections. If that's what you want however, check out https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need to do something like that:

```
var ModelOne = Backbone.Model.extend({
    method : function() {
        console.log('ModelOne > method');
    },
    sayHello : function() {
        console.log('ModelOne > hello');
    }
});

var ModelTwo = ModelOne.extend({
    method : function() {
        ModelOne.prototype.method.apply(this);
        console.log('ModelTwo > method');
    }
});

var methodTwo = new ModelTwo();
methodTwo.method();
methodTwo.sayHello();
```

Output:

```
ModelOne > method
ModelTwo > method
ModelOne > hello
```

Answer (score 0):

One more variation of setting `Backbone.Model` to the attribute of another model is to set it as default value:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: null,
        name: null,
        address: new AddressModel()
    }
});

var someUser = new UserModel();
    someUser.address.set('country', 'ZA');
```

When you are doing `someUser.save()` data enclosed in `someUser.attributes.address` will be a *usual data object*.

---

<kbd>!</kbd> One thing not yet tested **by me** is population of `AddressModel` upon `someUser.fetch()`